# Gradle sync failed: Could not load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModelImpl'

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

I am using Android 3.2.1 and gradle sync failed due to this issue:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not load class
>   'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModelImpl' from
>   jar:file:/Users/homemac/.gradle/caches/jars-3/05f59621515b1f3f3c4b4e77708df7a3/kotlin-gradle-tooling.jar!/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/KotlinGradleModelImpl.class.

Would anyone know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of caches

execute this in  terminal

```
./gradlew clean
```

then android studio menu

```
file->invalidate caches and restart
```

**Note :** Now android studio 3.5 is available.if possible update your android studio